# export/import class to test its methods and constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babel-jest

I am stuck on knowing how to test a class.

`ship.js`

```js
class Ship {
    /**
     * Constructor for setting up a ship object
     * @param {Number} length length of the ship
     * @param {Number} hits how many times the ship has been hit
     * @param {Boolean} isSunk If the ship is sunk
     */
    constructor(length, hits = 0, isSunk = false) {
        this.length = length;
        this.hits = hits;
        this.isSunk = isSunk;
    }

    /**
     * When a ship is hit by a player, or computer, increase it's hit count.
     */
    hit() {
        this.hits += 1;
    }

    /**
     * If the length of the ship is equal to the number of hits, the ship is sunk.
     */
    checkHitsToSink() {
        this.length === this.hits ? (this.isSunk = true) : null;
    }
}

/**
 * Exporting for unit testing
 */
module.exports = Ship;
```

`tests/ship.test.js`

```js
const Ship = require('../ship');

test('ship should be {length: 3, hits: 2, isSunk: false}', () => {
    const ship = new Ship(3, 2, false);
    require(ship).toHaveProperty('length', 3);
});
```

This outputs `TypeError: moduleName.startsWith is not a function` when I try running this test:

```
PS C:\Users\brand\Desktop\github\Battleship> npm test

> webpack-template@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  src/tests/ship.test.js
  × ship should be {length: 3, hits: 2, sunk: false} (2 ms)

  ● ship should be {length: 3, hits: 2, sunk: false}

    TypeError: moduleName.startsWith is not a function

      3 | test('ship should be {length: 3, hits: 2, sunk: false}', () => {
      4 |       const ship = new Ship(3, 2, false);
    > 5 |       require(ship).toHaveProperty(length, 3);
        |       ^
      6 | });
      7 |

      at Resolver.isCoreModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:452:20)
      at Object.require (src/tests/ship.test.js:5:2)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.707 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Is there a way to test a class doing it like this, or is there a different way completely on testing classes?

I have tried multiple ways to test this class (such as using ESM import/export statements, trying to pass the constructor or the class's methods directly into `module.exports`, and a few others), but I am coming up with TypeErrors, ReferenceErrors and SyntaxErrors.

Comment: Your exporting class seems ok. Do you have any other code in the same file where the Ship class is ?

In your test you are calling the Ship construction wrong:
` new Ship({length: 3, hits: 2, sunk: false});` - it should be ` new Ship({3,2, false);`

It is strange that you have `sunc` private prop and `isSunc` function

Comment: I had just started creating this project, so the ship.js class is what you see above. It does sound a bit odd having a `sunk` prop and `isSunk` function, which I followed [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/node-path-javascript-battleship)'s named function. I'll give this a change to have a name more reasonable.

You are correct about me calling the constructor wrong - I messed around with it and see the differences between the two now. Let me update the question

Comment: may you share full error message for TypeError: moduleName.startsWith is not a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a correct version:

```js
const Ship = require('../ship');

test('ship should be {length: 3, hits: 2, isSunk: false}', () => {
    const ship = new Ship(3, 2, false);
    expect(ship).toHaveProperty('length', 3);
});
```

the error was caused you use *require* instead of *expect* inside test body.

Comment: Oh lord.... This was the error all along, and I kept retyping it out over and over again.

Thanks so much for the help, this is quite embarrassing for me ahaha...

Comment: np, it is always good to have one more pair of eyes at the code=)